# Престал отображаться сайт в мобильных

Tags: android, html, css

Тема сайта ROOT. Сайт: https://kuhnianasha.ru/
После того, как поигрался в Вордпресе с «НАСТРОЙКИ — ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ СТИЛИ» перестало отображаться тело сайта на мобильных и планшетах. Отображается только фон сайта. На ПК сайт виден нормально. (я добавлял CSS стили на сайт в "Дополнительные стили") При удалении всех стилей сайт снова появляется на мобильном. Вот, что я добавил :

```css
.site {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.site {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .site {
    display: none;
  }
}

.grecaptcha-badge {
  display: none !important;
}

.search-form__text {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.rpwwt-widget {
  width: 330px;
  height: 699px;
  border: 6px double #B8860B;
  background: #FAEBD7;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.content-area {}

.site-main {
  border: 6px double #B8860B;
  width: 735px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #FAEBD7;
}

.page-separator {
  display: none
}

.wprm-container-float-right {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 09px;
}

.page-numbers {
  border: 2px double #B8860B;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #ccc, 0 0 7px #ccc inset;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Давайте больше информации: Как поигрались, что изменили, что изменилось в коде. Как отображалось, что сейчас и т.д. Иначе помочь Вам довольно сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Так вы же сами сайт скрываете на разрешениях меньше `1024px`:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .site {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Решилась проблема.